# Using an XSLT param in an XPath expression

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

When I use my XPath expression with a hardcoded variable, it gives me the right result:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//n-gram[@frequency > 50])"/>
```

But when I use a parameter of my template, it gives me a complete different result:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//n-gram[@frequency > $freq])"/>
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Complete code as reference (I'm generating a XAML file with XSL):

XML file:

```
<n-grams>
<n-gram frequency="3">r n u</n-gram>
<n-gram frequency="1">o H e</n-gram>
<n-gram frequency="2">r n t</n-gram>
<n-gram frequency="2">N i c</n-gram>
<n-gram frequency="2">a u l</n-gram> ...
```

XSL templates:

```
    <xsl:template name="fill-table">
    <xsl:param name="freq"/>
    <xsl:param name="startRow"/>
    <xsl:param name="startCol"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="get-textblock">
        <xsl:with-param name="row">
            <xsl:value-of select="$startRow "/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="column">
            <xsl:value-of select="$startCol + 1"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//n-gram[@frequency > $freq])"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="'ValueText'"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="get-textblock">
    <xsl:param name="row"/>
    <xsl:param name="column"/>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:param name="colspan" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="TextBlock">
        <xsl:attribute name="Grid.Column">
            <xsl:value-of select="$column"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Grid.Row">
            <xsl:value-of select="$row"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Style">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('{StaticResource ',$type,'}')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Grid.ColumnSpan">
            <xsl:value-of select="$colspan"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't shown to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is `$freq` really a number ?

use `[@frequency  > number($freq)]` to force casting the param

Comment: Okay thank you, that did the trick. The weird thing is that other times I didn't had to force the casting.

Comment: nice to know it works. yes, depends on how data is 'stored' and how you pass it to your fill-table template

Comment: `>` operator performs an implicit casting, from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans: _"the objects are compared by converting both objects to numbers and comparing the numbers according to IEEE 754"_. This is not the problem.

Comment: Ok strange. so what could it be ? not a w3c xslt implementation  ?